# Gitlab no active runners. Why

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have instal gitlab and gitlab-runner via docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:11.3.1-ce.0
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
    - /var/gitlab/etc:/etc/gitlab
    - /var/gitlab/opt:/var/opt/gitlab
    - /var/gitlab/log:/var/log/gitlab
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
    - "10022:22"
    environment:
    - "TZ=Europe/Moscow"
  gitlab-runner:
    container_name: gitlab-runner
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
    volumes:
    - /var/gitlab-runner/data:/home/gitlab_ci_multi_runner/data
    - /var/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw
    environment:
    restart: unless-stopped
```

And then I have register the runner in gitlab-ci like this:

```
docker-compose run gitlab-runner register -n \
--docker-privileged --registration-token QyGZmTbPCtwAsLytGmF8 \
--executor docker --description "Global docker runner" \
--docker-image "docker:latest" --url http://gitlab/
```

And after that I have no active runner.

[image: The list of runners]

The list of runners is always grow but no one runner is active.

Why does no one runner is active? Why it always reregister?

Comment: i guess you are missing enabling your runners in Gitlab ```Your Project -> Settings -> CI/CD -> Runners```

Comment: Why one runner is registering unlimited times but can't be an active state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an error.
Error was in

```
docker-compose run gitlab-runner register -n \
--docker-privileged --registration-token QyGZmTbPCtwAsLytGmF8 \
--executor docker --description "Global docker runner" \
--docker-image "docker:latest" --url http://gitlab/
```

This command start new gitlab-runner_run command. And it make unlimited containers and shutodwn it. 
I have run command inside started container and now it's ok!